# Manipulate delimiter between control and content

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

Is it possible to stylize `Manipulate` so that there is a line separating the control and the content? The code

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}],
 {x, 10, 100, 1},
 {y, 10, 100, 1},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

gives

[image]

but I'm looking for something like

[image]

Playing around with `Framed` and the option `Paneled` I can do something like

```
Framed[Manipulate[Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}],
  {x, 10, 100, 1},
  {y, 10, 100, 1},
  ControlPlacement -> Left, Paneled -> False], FrameMargins -> 10]
```

which gives

[image]

Now I would just need to include a line. Just an idea. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most general solution is to do the whole layout yourself.

You can actually use `Control` and put the controls themselves in the `Grid` along with your output.

So you will have only ONE grid, which now includes everything in it. Both the controls and the final output of your Manipulate code. This gives you full control of what you want to do. For your example, you can then do

```
Manipulate[ 
 Grid[{
   {Grid[{
      {"x", Control[{x, 10, 100, 1}]},
      {"y", Control[{y, 10, 100, 1}]}
      }]
    ,
    Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
    }
   }, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Gray]
 ,
 Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

And if you want just a line between the controls and the plot then

```
Manipulate[ 
 Grid[{
   {Grid[{
      {"x", Control[{x, 10, 100, 1}]},
      {"y", Control[{y, 10, 100, 1}]}
      }]
    ,
    Item[Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}], 
     Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}]}
   }]
 ,
 Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

But now since you have everything inside a Grid, you can play with the layout as you want. For example, you can do this

```
Manipulate[ 
 Grid[{
   {Grid[{
      {"x", Control[{x, 10, 100, 1}]},
      {"y", Control[{y, 10, 100, 1}]}
      }]
    },
   {
    Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
    }
   }, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> {Dashed, Red}, Spacings -> {1, 1}]
 ,
 Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

Or you can put one control above, and one below

```
Manipulate[ 
 Grid[{
   {"x", Control[{x, 10, 100, 1}]},
   {Item[Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}], Frame -> All], 
    SpanFromLeft},
   {"y", Control[{y, 10, 100, 1}]}
   }, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray, Spacings -> {1, 1}
  ]
 ,
 Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

And so on. The choices are  limitless.

You can change the style of the `Frame` and change the size of the controls as well. Basically you can now use all the styling available for `Grid` and `Frame` as you want and not worry about `Manipulate` itself.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to simply leave the `Manipulate` away, since at this point, it's neither doing control construction nor localization of variables?

Comment: @LukasLang sorry, I do not understand what you mean by `leave the Manipulate away`.

Comment: I was originally thinking that you could just keep the `Grid[...]` part without the `Manipulate` wrapper. You only have to add `Dynamic` around the plot (which would otherwise be done by `Manipulate`, and it would work the same. But I think it's better to actually tell `Manipulate` what the variables of your controls are, see my answer for the details

Comment: Great answer! I suppose that with this approach it is not possible to keep the "more options circular extender" that usually appears within the `Manipulate` content (top right corner) still only on the right panel, correct?

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This solution is heavily based on the one by @Nasser, this is just to show how to make better use of* `Manipulate`.

Here's how I would do it:

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[
  {{
    Grid[
     {{"x", Control[{x, 10, 100, 1}]},
      {"y", Control[{y, 10, 100, 1}]}}
     ],
    Item[
     Dynamic@Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}],
     Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}
     ]}}
  ],
 {{x, 10}, None}, {{y, 20}, None},
 Paneled -> False
 ]
```

[image]

The differences to the answer from @Nasser are:

- `Dynamic` wrapped around the plot. This makes sure the sliders work as expected, because otherwise dragging the slider will redraw the slider itself.
- `{{x, 10}, None}` as argument to `Manipulate`. This tells `Manipulate` that `x` should be one of the variables to localize, but that it shouldn't create a control. The `10` is the initial value for `x`, so you can easily set that as well. This should make the whole thing work better when restarting Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use the (undocumented) `Method` option `"ControlAreaDisplayFunction"` with a custom function that gives the desired look:

```
ClearAll[controlAreaDisplayFunction]
controlAreaDisplayFunction[side_: Right, itemsize_: Automatic, alignment_: Automatic, 
  spacings_: Automatic, style_: GrayLevel[0, .2]] := Grid[{{
    Item[#, ItemSize -> itemsize /. Automatic -> 
     (side /. {Right | Left -> {All, Scaled[1/3]}, Top | Bottom -> {Scaled[1/3], All}}),
    Frame -> MapAt[style &, {{None, None}, {None, None}}, 
      side /. {Top -> {2, 2}, Bottom -> {2, 1}, Left -> {1, 1}, Right -> {1, 2}}]]}},
   Alignment -> alignment /. Automatic -> 
     (side /. {Right -> {Left, Center}, Left -> {Right, Center},
          Top -> {Center, Top}, Bottom -> {Center, Bottom}}), 
   Spacings -> spacings /. Automatic -> 
     (side /. { Left | Right -> {5, 0}, Top | Bottom -> {0, 5}})] &
```

***Examples:***

```
Panel @ Manipulate[Plot3D[Sin[x + u + v + y^2], {u, -3, 3}, {v, -2, 2}, 
    ImageSize -> 300],
  {x, 10, 100, 1}, {y, 10, 100, 1}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left, 
  Paneled -> False, 
  Method -> {"ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> controlAreaDisplayFunction[]}]
```

[image]

Use `ControlPlacement -> Right` and `"ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> controlAreaDisplayFunction[Left]` to get

[image]

Use `ControlPlacement -> Bottom` and `"ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> controlAreaDisplayFunction[Top]` to get

[image]

Use `ControlPlacement -> Top` and `"ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> controlAreaDisplayFunction[Bottom]` to get

[image]

Replace `controlAreaDisplayFunction[Bottom` with `controlAreaDisplayFunction[Bottom, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Orange]]`  to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would it be somehow possible to actually make the vertical delimiter connect to the top and bottom horizontal delimiters just to avoid that tight spacing (first example)?

Comment: @samwolfe, unfortunately  I don't know how to make the delimiters to connect to the outer frame.

Comment: For some reason your solution is resulting and very long cell. Any idea why? I'm using Mathematica 12.2.

Comment: @samwolfe, I am using version 11.3. I tried the same code on version 12.3 (Wolfram Cloud) ; somehow, the control area is not centered.